# Node Webkit ember.js issue

Tags: node.js, ember.js, chromium, node-webkit

i am trying to package a simple ember.js example with node webkit in mac-os 10.8 but i am getting the specified error  **"Running without renderer sandbox"**. Is there any issue with using ember.js with nodeWebkit b'coz when i am packaging without using ember.js it's working.

Comment: Which version of nw are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The warning message "Running without renderer sandbox" can be ignored. node-webkit doesn't have sandboxes as Chromium does.

Comment: Sorry but i have found the solution, it was because i have given the height and width of the window 100% and in MacOs it was creating problem giving the height and width in px resolved my issue